# Not able to compile any Flutter project 'gradle:compileGroovy' error

Tags: flutter, gradle, compiler-errors

`Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain Could not write standard input to Gradle Worker Daemon 1.`

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

> Failed to run Gradle Worker Daemon
> Process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Have tried various solutins deleted .gradle file reinstalled grade and jdk and gradle but the this error presisted. Not able to compile any flutter project including the fresh porjects.
jdk version is 20
gradle version 8.1
flutter version is 3.19

Answer (score 0):

Clean the gradle by **./gradlew clean** command and ReInstall the Gradle Plugin from the Android Studio OR Modify the **build.gradle** or **graddle-wrapper-properties** file.

Comment: gradle commands give me the same error have updated my graddle-wrapper-properties file updated the gradle version to 8.3 sourceCompatibility and target Compatibility is set to version 1.8 any ohter suggestions?